# android app using .this

Tags: android

```
package com.example.arel0002.pizzeria;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

/**
 * Created by arel0002 on 2015-06-01.
 */
public class pizza extends Activity {
    Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainpage);
        View button = (View) findViewById(R.id.pizza);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent i = new Intent(mainpage.this, pizza.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I cant find why in mainpage. This it says: `com.exampel.pizzera` is not an enclosing class, I changed computer can that affect?

Best regard

Armando

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the following line

```
 Intent i = new Intent(mainpage.this, pizza.class);
```

your class is called `pizza` not `mainpage`. The first argument should be `pizza.this`, not `mainpage.this`. The second argument is the Activity you want to start. In your case you are starting a new instance of `pizza`. Aso you missed `);` in your `setOnClickListener`. It should be

```
setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent i = new Intent(mainpage.this, pizza.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
 });
```

Comment: the issues now became 
}
}

it says that ) and ; are expected (the 2 } in the middle)

Answer (score 0):

Your are not using proper intent constructor parameters.
The definition from the document is following-

```
/**
     * Create an intent for a specific component.  All other fields (action, data,
     * type, class) are null, though they can be modified later with explicit
     * calls.  This provides a convenient way to create an intent that is
     * intended to execute a hard-coded class name, rather than relying on the
     * system to find an appropriate class for you; see {@link #setComponent}
     * for more information on the repercussions of this.
     *
     * @param packageContext A Context of the application package implementing
     * this class.
     * @param cls The component class that is to be used for the intent.
     *
     * @see #setClass
     * @see #setComponent
     * @see #Intent(String, android.net.Uri , Context, Class)
     */
    public Intent(Context packageContext, Class<?> cls) {
        mComponent = new ComponentName(packageContext, cls);
    }
```

Your Intent instance can be like this-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(pizza.this,<TargetingActivity.class>)
```